# AFNetworking can easily return a UIImage, but how do I return NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, nsdata

I want to use [this](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/) category to create UIImage GIFs from NSData. I don't want to use the `dataWithContentsOfURL` method as it blocks the main thread, so I want to use AFNetworking as I normally do to get the NSData.

With images, I've always done something like this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.url]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *imageOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
imageOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

And then `start` it after a completion block. But that returns a UIImage. How can I asynchronously get NSData with AFNetworking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply don't use the image serializer. I think this should work:

```
imageOperation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

More about different AFNetworking serialization options [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#serialization).

Answer (score 4):

I just hacked a animated gif serialisation class together that uses Robs category.
It is — for sure — not complete, it will only work on iOS.

interface:

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h>

@interface VSAnimatedGIFResponseSerializer : AFImageResponseSerializer

@end
```

---

implementation:

```
#import "VSAnimatedGIFResponseSerializer.h"
#import "UIImage+animatedGIF.h"

@implementation VSAnimatedGIFResponseSerializer

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    self.acceptableContentTypes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: @"image/gif", nil];
    return self;
}

+ (NSSet *)acceptablePathExtensions {
    static NSSet * _acceptablePathExtension = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _acceptablePathExtension = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"gif", nil];
    });

    return _acceptablePathExtension;
}


- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    if (![self validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response data:data error:error]) {
        if ([(NSError *)(*error) code] == NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData) {
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:data];
}

@end
```

---

Usage:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bildschirmarbeiter.com/content/anigifs/animated-gifs-39/animated-gifs-39-001.gif"]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [VSAnimatedGIFResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage *responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:responseObject];

        imgView.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSURLConnection's [sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10), whose completion block returns NSData.

Or I suppose you could convert the UIImage retrieved from the AFNetworking method to NSData with [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW10) but that is a bit less efficient.